# UINavigationController items are not showing for some users

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

When I look to my app comments, I see that some people wonder why there is no "DONE" button to validate their registration form. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue so far.

Here is what people should see (note that there is a back button and a DONE button). Most people see that correctly as many users manage to complete their registration.
[image: What people should actually see]

We recently had a response from one of our user who sent us a screenshot. Also, she told us her phone is an iPhone 6S and she using iOS 10 (but we had complaints about the same issue since iOS 9)
[image: What some users see]

Technically speaking, nothing too fancy, the register form view controller is pushed on a UINavigationController. Views are declared in a XIB and navigation items are linked as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Navigation bar
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton

    [...]
}
```

Back button only impact the next screen (to prevent having text next to the arrow image).

Do you have any idea what could cause this issue? How I could reproduce? How I could fix maybe?

Thanks,
Cyril

Comment: Try running the app in simulator with same device and iOS version. Also check if the app contains accurate image resolutions.

Comment: Ran it in real devices and simulators using the same settings, no luck. Image resolution was a good idea for the back button, unfortunately, I have all resolutions available for it and this can not explain the DONE button (text) missing.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? I just ran into a similar situation where the back button doesn't appear on one test device, but is fine on the rest.